# Using wevtutil return a selected event attribute as text from a selected event record

Tags: events, xpath

I am trying to use wevtutil to extract the value of a particular attribute, ObjectName, (without tags) from the most recent audit event of a specific ID, 4663. I then want to place that in an environment variable for use in a batch file which is triggered by occurrences of 4663. I have copied in the xml for the event below.

I have got to the point of being able to select the event and output the XML using this syntax:

```
C:\Users\Mike>wevtutil qe security /q:"*[System [(EventID=4663)]]" /c:1 /rd:true
```

But I cannot work out how to retrieve just one attribute from within the event XML that results. Is it even possible? Xpath appears to provide the syntax, but does wevtutil support it?

I'd prefer to do it in one stage, but I understand wevtutil can output to a file so I guess you could then process that in some way.

Obviously if there were a better utility than wevtutil to do this I could use that.

Many thanks to anyone who can help.

Mike

**Event XML**

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
<Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" Guid="{54849625-5478-4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D}"/>
<EventID>4663</EventID>
<Version>0</Version>
<Level>0</Level>
<Task>12800</Task>
<Opcode>0</Opcode>
<Keywords>0x8020000000000000</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-12-07T16:50:28.582540600Z"/>
<EventRecordID>2637347</EventRecordID>
<Correlation/>
<Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="64"/>
<Channel>Security</Channel>
<Computer>Dell-8300-PC</Computer>
<Security/>
</System>
<EventData>
<Data Name="SubjectUserSid">S-1-5-21-1054466239-2335366426-2448288976-1001</Data>
<Data Name="SubjectUserName">Mike</Data>
<Data Name="SubjectDomainName">Dell-8300-PC</Data>
<Data Name="SubjectLogonId">0x4149a</Data>
<Data Name="ObjectServer">Security</Data>
<Data Name="ObjectType">File</Data>
<Data Name="ObjectName">D:\Mike's data\My Documents\fred</Data>
<Data Name="HandleId">0x12a74</Data>
<Data Name="AccessList">%%4418</Data>
<Data Name="AccessMask">0x4</Data>
<Data Name="ProcessId">0x1048</Data>
<Data Name="ProcessName">C:\Windows\explorer.exe</Data>
</EventData>
</Event>
```

Answer (score 0):

A strange discovery. If I use webtutil to write the whole event as a file, and I then edit that file to remove the string

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event"
```

and nothing else, I can access the data I require via
 PowerShell using this command:

```
PS> select-xml -path "C:\Users\Mike\xmltext1.xml" -Xpath "*//EventDat
a/Data[@Name = 'ObjectName']" | ForEach-Object {$_.Node.'#text'}
```

Which correctly returns:

```
C:\Program Files\MXContactEE\MXContact.pst
```

But the same command returns nothing unless I remove the 'xmlns' string from the file, which is inconvenient.

I'm lost as to why.....

Best wishes, Mouse

Comment: I checked the documentation on select-xml (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849968.aspx). Your XML is using the so-called "default namespace". The manual suggests to use an arbitrary prefix in the namespace declaration. So try this: `select-xml -hashtable @{p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event"} -path "C:\Users\Mike\xmltext1.xml" -Xpath "*//p:EventData/p:Data[@Name = 'ObjectName']" | ForEach-Object {$_.Node.'#text'}`

Comment: Thanks Marcus I will try that. Well found, sounds likely! I guess this probably explains the webtutil results too.

Comment: With a slight mod - the parameter is -namespace not hashtable it works from Powershell. Specifically this: `select-xml -namespace @{p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event"} -path "C:\Users\Mike\xmltext.xml" -Xpath "*//p:EventData/p:Data[@Name = 'ObjectName']" | ForEach-Object {$_.Node.'#text'}` correctly yielded: `C:\Program Files\MXContactEE\MXContact.pst`. I also replaced the file name by `xmltext.xml`, since that file contains the unedited XML output from webtutil. So I have a two stage way of doing it anyway :). Thanks very much Marcus!

Comment: You're welcome! I think you should modify your own answer to match your findings.

Answer (score 0):

The two stage solution, writing the event to a file in cmd.exe then processing it using select XML, almost works. Here are the commands I used. First in cmd.exe:

```
C:\Users\Mike> Wevtutil qe security /q:"*[System [(EventID=4663)]]" /c:1 /rd:true > xmltext.xml
```

Then in Powerwshell:

```
PS C:\scripts> Select-xml -namespace @{p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event"} -path "C:\Users\Mike\xmltext.xml" -Xpath "*//p:EventData/p:Data[@Name = 'ObjectName']" | ForEach-Object {$_.Node.'#text'}
```

Unfortunately the select-xml statement fails on meeting an unexpected end of file 2/3 of the way through the record. It does this even if you try the whole thing via a pipe in Powershell:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> & C:\windows\system32\wevtutil.exe --% qe security /q:*[System[(EventID=4663)]] /c:1 /rd:true | select-xml -namespace @{p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event"} -Xpath "*//p:EventData/p:Data[@Name = 'ObjectName']" | ForEach-Object {$_.Node.'#text'}
```

Both approaches yield (very quickly!) the following error:

```
select-xml : Cannot convert value "<Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'><System><Provider Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing' Guid
='{54849625-5478-4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D}'/><EventID>4663</EventID><Version>0</Version><Level>0</Level><Task>12800</Task><Opcode>0</Opcode><Keywords>0x8020000000000000</K
eywords><TimeCreated SystemTime='2013-12-14T12:19:50.172177700Z'/><EventRecordID>3598848</EventRecordID><Correlation/><Execution ProcessID='4' 
ThreadID='52'/><Channel>Security</Channel><Computer>Dell-8300-PC</Computer><Security/></System><EventData><Data 
Name='SubjectUserSid'>S-1-5-21-1054466239-2335366426-2448288976-1001</Data><Data Name='SubjectUserName'>Mike</Data><Data 
Name='SubjectDomainName'>Dell-8300-PC</Data><Data Name='SubjectLogonId'>0x39533</Data><Data Name='ObjectServer'>Security</Data><Data Name='ObjectType'>File</Data><Data 
Name='ObjectName'>C:\Program Files\MXContactEE\MXContact.pst</Data><Data Name='HandleId'>0x4ef0</Data><Data Name='AccessList'>%%4416" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". 
Error: "Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: Data, EventData, Event. Line 1, position 980."
At line:1 char:97
+ & C:\windows\system32\wevtutil.exe --% qe security /q:*[System[(EventID=4663)]]  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Xml], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastToXmlDocument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectXmlCommand

select-xml : Cannot convert value "                </Data><Data Name='AccessMask'>0x1</Data><Data Name='ProcessId'>0x1b4c</Data><Data Name='ProcessName'>C:\Program 
Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE</Data></EventData></Event>" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "Unexpected end tag. Line 1, position 7."
At line:1 char:97
+ & C:\windows\system32\wevtutil.exe --% qe security /q:*[System[(EventID=4663)]]  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Xml], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastToXmlDocument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectXmlCommand
```

It appears the reason that it sees an end of file is that there are Tab characters in the EventXML. (I looked at the webtutil output file using a disk sector editor and at the point select-xml gives up processing there is a sequence of 4 Tab characters plus maybe a carriage return or two after the access list data item. It also shows up in the formatted event in event viewer though strangely not in the XML.). The reason that did not happen with the file I originally created and tested in the last answer was, I think, that I screen-scraped the output and pasted it into a file instead of writing it to file, or possibly that I did a .NET reinstall in between.

The problem could I guess be fixed with a stream character filter, but I don't know how to do that for a non-printing character like a tab.

So I ended up with a one-stage solution (well more correctly a solution with no intermediate file) using Powershell, as follows:

```
$events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ProviderName="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing"; id=4663}
$event = [xml]$events[0].ToXml()
$ObjectName=$event.Event.EventData.Data | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "ObjectName"}
$ObjectName."#text"
```

Which rather slowly but correctly gives:

```
C:\Program Files\MXContactEE\MXContact.pst
```

I adapted that solution from here:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/5aa133b0-ea69-4348-9bac-d028ba895024/powershell-obtaining-eventdata-from-a-specific-event?forum=ITCG

So we have a solution of sorts, albeit a slow one, and not involving webtutil. One could get to dislike Microsoft a bit after this experience. What are the tabs doing there?

Many thanks Marcus for all your help with this!

Best wishes

Mike